# Isaac Wasserman: How can look at all of the source code for an iOS app?

Tags: ios

[3/16/15, 7:38:28 PM] Isaac Wasserman: I want to make an app that uses similar mechanics to Madden mobile. I want to look at the code using Xcode, but it doesn’t seem like I can read it if it’s not a project. It contains .viv files.

Comment: Contact the developers, maybe they want to share parts of the code that you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the code from the app, the app is a compiled binary. On top of that it is encrypted so even getting the binary is difficult.

Even if you could that would be stealing unless you had explicit permission.

Answer (score 1):

If you have connections with the developer they might give you the source, but that's about it. You can always take notes on what the app does that you want to replicate and then come up with your own solution to accomplish it.